# compress UIImage but keep size

Tags: ios, image-processing

I try to use `UIImageView` to show the photo. But the Photo sometimes is a little large, and I want to compress it.But I'd like to keep its size.
For example,a photo is 4M and has a size of 320X480. And I want to compress it and it may have 1M but still has a size of 320X480.

thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Compress it using the JPEG compression.

```
lowResImage = [UIImage imageWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(highResImage, quality)];
```

Where quality is between 0.0 and 1.0

*You should read the [UIImage documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html), everything is explained in there…*

Comment: currently I use this way. But as you see: image->data->image, will it consumer too much?

Comment: As you don't want to reduce the image size (width/height), but the data representation (the bits) of this image, i don't think there is a really better way. JPEG compression is not immediate but if you want to compress the data anyway...

Comment: The only other way I see would be to draw the `UIImage` on a `CGBitmapContext` with lower quality, but for this case you will need to loose on colorspace depth for example (less colors) or size (smaller image dimensions), and not on the NSBitmapRepresentation (the encoding/compression of the pixels in bits using JPEG, PNG, TIFF, RAW, RLE...)  of the image (it may even be worse as, then, the resulting `UIImage` drawn on the new `CGBitmapContext` will very likely be using RAW pixels without any compression at all...)

Comment: Do you know how can i do it but for a PNG image?

Answer (score 3):

If your goal is to get the image below a specific data length, it's tough to guess what compression ratio you need, unless you know the source image will always be a certain data length. Here's a simple iterative approach that uses jpeg compression to achieve a target length... let's say 1MB, to match the question:

```
// sourceImage is whatever image you're starting with

NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] init];
for (float compression = 1.0; compression >= 0.0; compression -= .1) {
    imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(sourceImage, compression);
    NSInteger imageLength = imageData.length;
    if (imageLength < 1000000) {
        break;
    }
}
UIImage *finalImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

I've seen some approaches that use a `while` loop to compresses the image by .9 or whatever until the target size is met, but I think you'd be losing image quality and processor cycles by successively compressing/reconstituting the image.  Also, the `for` loop here is a little safer because it stops automatically after trying the maximum possible compression (zero).