# Compress imagesize during runtime

Tags: android, ios, memory, image-size

Im having some memory issues with my app. It can pick an image from the users personal gallery and store it in a file to be rendered on the screen. The issue is that the limitation on the imagesize is very small. Which I have discovered lead to pretty much every image on my device being to large to handle. So the method itself became useless since it can't handle moderate sized images. I'm experiencing this only on ios devices so far.

Is there a solution? Can I compress/minimize the size of the image to a smaller one in any way? Cutting all images to the same resolution? (Like Instagram's system).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to reduce the image size in bytes, there are at least 3 areas you can work on:

1. Reduce image dimensions (pixel resolution). This almost always
   causes loss of quality, but if your users are viewing on small
   screen devices, and you don't resize too much, the loss won't be
   significant. You can also use interpolation to minimize the visual
   degradation when resizing.
2. Reduce bit depth (color resolution).If the image is full color (32
   or 24 bits per pixel), you can sometimes get away with reducing it
   to a lower color count such as making it 8-bit. Again this will
   cause quality loss, but you can use dithering to reduce it.
3. Use better compression. Most images are
   already compressed these days, but in some cases you can re-compress
   an image to make the file smaller. One example is JPEG which
   supports different quality factors. There are also different
   sub-types (color sampling frequencies) in JPEG. So if you save an
   image as 4:1:1 instead of 4:4:4, it will contain less color content
   and become smaller in byte size, but the difference is usually not
   noticeable to the human eye. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8112166) has details on changing
   JPEG Quality factor on iOS.